# Styling pop up menu with actionbarcompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-popupwindow

I've `PopUpMenu` with support library v7 in my application which works as expected. But styling `PopUpMenu` is not working with styles of `actionbarcompat`.

`styles.xml` in values as follows :

```
<style name="Theme.Tellus" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tellus</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tellus</item>
</style>


<style name="PopupMenu.Tellus" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tellus</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_tellus</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Tellus" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tellus</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Here is output what I'm getting after applying theme.
[image]

*It does display background of `PopUpMenu` in blue color which is applied from `dropDownListViewStyle`. How come `PopUpMenu` using `dropDownListViewStyle`? If it's using then it should use all attributes of `dropDownListViewStyle`*

*I want to change `MenuItem textColor` to `white` which fits to my theme. How can one apply style to `MenuItem` textColor?*

*Any enlightenment will be welcomes*

Answer (score 0):

try like this -

```
    <style name="Theme.Tellus" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tellus</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tellus</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```